# up to date, audited 1 package in 513ms found 0 vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I removed My `node_modules` folder, `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. when i run `npm install` it says **"up to date, audited 1 package in 513ms
found 0 vulnerabilities"** and there is no `node_modules` was installed.

`package.json` is
`{}`

`package-lock.json` is `{ "name": "client", "lockfileVersion": 2, "requires": true, "packages": {} }`

Comment: Try `npm list`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you removed the `package.json` file, NodeJS assumes you are initializing a new project and create an empty  `package.json` for you. Obviously, it won't install any packages for you because you didn't specify any in the first place.